# App Crashes when Click on Add (Hinzufügen)

Tags: android, android-studio

I Buying an Dating App always works fine. But when i Click the Add (in German Hinzufügen) Button the App Crashes. The Other Add Buttons works fine.

I Seek to Answers on Google but im not finding. And i must say im an Newbie in Java.

```
Process: de.kara.firedate, PID: 10759
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Hinzufügen"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:801)
    at de.kara.firedate.Profile.ProfileEditActivity.ProfileDialogSeekbar(ProfileEditActivity.java:1799)
    at de.kara.firedate.Profile.ProfileEditActivity.access$300(ProfileEditActivity.java:54)
    at de.kara.firedate.Profile.ProfileEditActivity$34.onClick(ProfileEditActivity.java:592)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299)
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

---

ProfileEditActivity.Java Line 1799:

```
    // set the custom layout
    final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_seekbar, null);
    builder.setView(customLayout);


    TextView textViewProfileEditSeekbarLeft = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfileEditSeekbarLeft);
    TextView textViewProfileEditSeekbarRight = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfileEditSeekbarRight);
    CrystalSeekbar seekbarProfileEditSeekbarSlider = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.seekbarProfileEditSeekbarSlider);
    seekbarProfileEditSeekbarSlider.setMinValue(dialogMin);
    seekbarProfileEditSeekbarSlider.setMaxValue(dialogMax);


    String dialogTextString = dialogTextView.getText().toString();

    if (!dialogTextString.equals("Add")) {

        String[] splitDialogTextView = new String[10];
        int valueDialogTextView;

        if (dialogUser.equals("user_height")) {
            splitDialogTextView = dialogTextString.split("cm");
        }
        if (dialogUser.equals("user_weight")) {
            splitDialogTextView = dialogTextString.split("kg");
        }

        valueDialogTextView = Integer.valueOf(splitDialogTextView[0]);
        seekbarProfileEditSeekbarSlider.setMinStartValue(valueDialogTextView);
        seekbarProfileEditSeekbarSlider.apply();
    }
```

---

ProfileEditActivity.java Line 54:

public class ProfileEditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

---

ProfileEditActivity.java Line 592:

```
    linearLayoutProfileEditHeight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProfileDialogSeekbar(textViewProfileEditHeight,
                    "user_height", "Select your Height", 140, 240);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The exception is at line no. 1799

Comment: Yes the line is:

valueDialogTextView = Integer.valueOf(splitDialogTextView[0]);
        seekbarProfileEditSeekbarSlider.setMinStartValue(valueDialogTextView);
        seekbarProfileEditSeekbarSlider.apply();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse a string that does not contain a parsable integer.
Since `Integer.valueOf` throws `NumberFormatException` you should handle it by using `try{}catch{}` block.

for instance

```
    try {
        valueDialogTextView = Integer.valueOf(splitDialogTextView[0]);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        valueDialogTextView = -1; // just a default value to be set , indicate failure
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I try this but have the same issue. All other Buttons in app like add weight is working only the add height button crashes

Comment: @FerhatTerzi according to your stack trace you try to convert the word **Hinzufügen** to `int` , that's throws exception and your app will crush.

Comment: ok but why the other Buttons works? only Größe (Height) Hinzufügen button crashes the other Hinzufügen buttons dont crash when i click. https://ibb.co/zX1gF1q

Comment: So i tested the app on other Phone and its works fine. On my Samsung S9+ API Lvl 28 Crashes i have no idea how can i resolve this issue. Thank You for your Time. Best Regards